# Android Studio : Dialog Box not keeping the same format as its custom layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

On completing an order in my application a dialog box opens with a custom layout .xml file, for some further options. The dialog box has some of the features of the custom layout like color and some of the buttons but doesn't show it correctly. I tried playing with the dimensions of the layout but unfortunately it doesn't fix the format issue.

Any help appreciated!

[image: This is what the layout looks like in the .xml file]

[image: This is what it looks like in the application]

Here is the code for the dialog box

`

```
private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
private AlertDialog dialog;
private Button btnCard, btn50, btn20, btn10, btn5, btnCancel, btnReturnO;
private int stopperDialog =0;
public void finishOrderDialog(){
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final View finishPopupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    btnCard = (Button) finishPopupView.findViewById(R.id.btnCard);
    btn50 = (Button) finishPopupView.findViewById(R.id.btn50);
    btn20 = (Button) finishPopupView.findViewById(R.id.btn20);
    btn10 = (Button) finishPopupView.findViewById(R.id.btn10);
    btn5 = (Button) finishPopupView.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btnCancel = (Button) finishPopupView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnReturnO = (Button) finishPopupView.findViewById(R.id.btnReturnO);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    dialogBuilder.setView(finishPopupView);
    dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, (4*height)/5);
    

    btnReturnO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}`
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:text="Cancel Order"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#F80000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.616"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.346"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnReturnO"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:text="Return to Order"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#F80000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.616"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.646"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn50"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:text="50"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#00BEF8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCard"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:text="Card"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#85F800"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.398" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn20"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:text="20"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#00BEF8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.346"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn10"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:text="10"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#00BEF8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.646"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn5"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#00BEF8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.946"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste your XML file for custom layout

Comment: @AjayKS Sorry! It's been added above

Comment: ther problem is all about your xml code try to make constraints to the buttons from top then you can achieve the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try change your xml like this

[image: part 1]

[image: part 2]

your problem is to set layout_constraint every button,
hope can solve your problem :)

Comment: Yes this solved my problem, thank you!